# How can I fix "sessionStorage is not defined" in Svelte?

Tags: svelte, sapper

I'm new in Svelte and I'm trying to set some info into sessionStorage but it is throwing "sessionStorage is not defined".
I realised that I received this error because it's running on the server side.

I created a component at */src/components/nav.svelte* that uses */src/domain/auth/service.js* and the error occurs in the last one.

Searching on the web I found that in this case I must use **sessionStorage** inside **onMount** function. Is that the right way?

How can I avoid that my code get a little mess?

Comment: what data you are trying to store? are you going to use the data in both server side and client side?

Comment: You indeed found the correct answer. You would use sessionStorage inside the onMount function as this will only run when your attaching the component on the client. The cost inside onMount will specifically NOT run on the server so that you are able to lazily load data on the client side.

Comment: I put code which contains sessionStorage into functions and it stopped complains. 
But now it shows me the following warning: "Using browser-only version of superagent in non-browser environment"
Do I need to worry about it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try to check if you're actually in a browser environment, e.g. something like

```
if (window && window.sessionStorage) {
    // do your stuff with sessionStorage
}
```

or

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    // do your stuff with sessionStorage
}
```

Comment: For me, the latter works but the former doesn't (SvelteKit): `ReferenceError: window is not defined`

Comment: Note to self: Don't call `sessionStorage.setItem()` in a [reactive statement (`$:`)](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-3-$-marks-a-statement-as-reactive) since it will reset the stored value to the initial state on every refresh.

Answer (score 12):

hey you need to use onMount

```
import { onMount } from 'svelte';

onMount(() => {
    sessionStorage.setItem('myWork', 'Developer');
});
```

Comment: Or, you may need `afterUpdate` instead of `onMount`, to trigger some action on dom update. For me, after `await goto(`/`);`, need to use `afterUpdate` to read `sessionStorage` to make sure it works, when use `onMount` I need a refresh by hand sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

While exsides approach is valid, [Sveltekit's recommended approach](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-environment) is;

```js
import { browser } from '$app/environment';
```

then

```js
if (browser) {
    // do your stuff with sessionStorage...
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for the addition, didn't know about that one! Did that exist at the time I wrote the answer?

Comment: I don't think it was. 

Comment: @exside I think it was introduced recently, in the last 2 years maybe. it is the one I use more often since it makes sense semantically speaking.